# How do I get the Kubuntu Application menu to appear above its button

Tags: kubuntu, start-menu, kde-4

Just installed a fresh Kubuntu 11.04 (plus wifi and nvidia drivers).

Got a weird but annoying issue whereby my App Launcher menu is appearing at the top of my screen when I click the button for it at the bottom of the screen as per screenshot (right-click, view image for full size original, 1.2mb)

Only theory I have is my dual-screen setup.

[image: K button at bottom, menu at top]

Any ideas how I can get the menu to appear above the button, a la Windows?

Comment: Please note this is a pure KDE environment and as such (probably) doesn't have anything to do with the Unity Desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like resetting and reapplying my TwinView settings and ensuring they were written out to my xorg.conf seems to have resolved this.  I 've subsequently upgraded to 11.10 and the fix seems to have stuck

Answer (score 1):

The article [Ubuntu 11.04 – What Have They Done?!](http://journalxtra.com/2011/04/ubuntu-11-04-what-have-they-done/) also rails mightily about
the [Unity user interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28user_interface%29). Designed for netbooks and other small screened mobile devices, the developers purposefully saved screen space by making the changes that you don't like.

The article terminates by :

> 9 hours later, after installing the Kubuntu Desktop Environment
>   alongside Ubuntu along with many updates, upgrades and software
>   packages, I have discovered I can have a taskbar at the bottom of my
>   Ubuntu 11.04 desktop. To get Natty Ubuntu looking somewhat similar to
>   Maverick you must change your desktop environment to “Ubuntu Classic”
>   when you log in by clicking your username then changing “Ubuntu” (in
>   the dropdown box) at the bottom of the screen to “Ubuntu Classic”. I
>   would never have realized this had I not installed KDE.

Comment: Yes, but I just installed Kubuntu (ie, KDE only) from the start, so AFAIK, never had a Unity interface.

Comment: I'm not using Kubuntu, so cannot check anything. Do you have anywhere a "Ubuntu Classic" option ?

Comment: Sadly not, but I did manage to resolve the issue - see my self-answer